# Is there a way to fully map a valid SQL logging statement with Spring JPA without parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

With spring JPA is there a way to get valid sql in a log statement without the parameterized sql from the prepared statement.

I can see the SQL with my debug settings below, but the data is parameterized.  Is there a way for it to generate sql like the following below.

Parameterized from log:

2021-12-12 17:54:37.414 DEBUG 10185 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.SQL

insert into DB2PROD.GLOBAL_TABLE (AGENT) values (?)

```
2021-12-12 17:54:37.415 TRACE 10185 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [N]
2021-12-12 17:54:37.415 TRACE 10185 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - []
```

I see the values but I have to manually insert them to build the proper query.  Is there something that would make it automatic.

```
Insert into table value('N') for example.
```

I am currently using this settings.

```
# Log Settings
logging.level.root: ${JPA_LOG_LEVEL}
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: ${JPA_LOG_LEVEL}
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: ${JPA_LOG_LEVEL}
# Enable parameter binding (set to trace for param values), useful during debugging
# For most verbose logging, add in startup script:
# export JPA_LOG_LEVEL=TRACE
#  export SQL_LOG_LEVEL=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.type: trace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

The second line displays the prepared statement parameters

Comment: Can I map them to valid SQL.   I have the parameters but for larger set of parameters, difficult to to the sql.